# Не изменяется цвет обьекта в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Я создал объект Plane в другом родительском элементе Map, нажав по нему в иерархии. Попытался изменить цвет Plane, но не вышло, категория с материалом не доступна и затемнена, на клики не реагирует. Тоже самое происходит и с другими объектами.
Почему так происходит, и как это можно решить?
Скриншот - https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/839053033954344960/861610914273034270/Screenshot_7.png?width=981&height=545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй создать новый материал и повесить его на `Plane`. Потом пробуй изменить цвет. Также удали из  `Plane` материал `Default Material`.